# remapping arbitary curves

Tags: matlab, image-processing, transformation

[image]

Two curves with a set of known pixel coordinates are shown at the image above.  Is there a way to transform the outer curve into a circle and then remap the inner curve such that the distances at all points between the two curves and the area between the two curves are preserved?

One way that I thought that I would do this is by splitting the region in between the two curves into smaller quadrilateral sections.  The top and bottom of the quadrilateral will be the outer and inner curves with a predetermined length. The sides of the quadrilateral run laterally between the two curves and should be straight. After the transformation, the outer curve will be a circular arc and the inner curve will adjust according to the pre-transform distances in order to preserve distance. In order to preserve area, the lateral lines of the quadrilateral will adjust the angles at which they were orientated, but still remain straight, to preserve area.

The problem is that I can't think of a way to code this or how I would split the region into smaller sections.

If there are any other suggestions on how I can approach my problem I am open to them.

Comment: I think it will be very hard to define how the distance is preserved between points on the two curves after the curves are transformed. But, since area is preserved you know directly what the radius of the circle will be on the outer curve on the image to the right. You could maybe start from there.

Comment: Is there a way to go pixel by pixel on the one of the lines and find the vectors between a pixel on one line and a pixel on the other?

Comment: You could try `bwboundaries` and then go through the points. But, there will be more points on the outer boundary than the inner, so that approach seems futile.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's possible to preserve both the area and the distance. It is possible to preserve the area and the proportional distance (from the centre of the outer circle in the original drawing - i.e., the point (mean(x), mean(y)), if x and y are the list of x-coords and y-coords of the original shape), or the distance only. The following is an illustrative example:

Edit: I thought about it a little more, and in the below code you have the parameter of the outer circle's radius, which can be freely changed to affect the area without changing the line length. You should turn the code below into a function, omitting the part that scales the area, of course,  and use one of the optimisation functions to find the radius of the outer circle that gets the closest area with the same line lengths.

```
% Area normalisation flag
norm_area = true;

% Start with two circles, perturb them randomly
N = 100;
phi = linspace(0, 2*pi, N)';

% Set radii
r = [2 4];

% Generate data
r_pert = repmat(r, N, 1);

% Filter some random data (so it's smoothish)
filtOrd = 20;
b = ones(1, filtOrd) / filtOrd;
randData = filter(b, 1, randn(size(r_pert)));
randData = bsxfun(@minus, randData, mean(randData));
r_pert = r_pert + randData;

% Initial plot
close all;
polar(phi, r_pert(:, 2));
hold on;
polar(phi, r_pert(:, 1));

% Generate circle that encloses all radii
r_pureCirc = max(r_pert(:));

% Line lengths
lens = abs(r_pert(:, 2) - r_pert(:, 1));

r_pertCirc = r_pureCirc - lens;

% Calculate area of new and old shapes
% Elemental area is a pie slice between phi(n) - dphi/2 and phi + dphi/2
dphi = phi(2) - phi(1);
dA_orig = dphi * (r_pert(:, 2) .^ 2 - r_pert(:, 1) .^ 2) / 2;
dA_new = dphi * (r_pureCirc .^ 2 - r_pertCirc .^ 2) / 2;
A_orig = sum(dA_orig);
A_new = sum(dA_new);

r_new = [r_pertCirc repmat(r_pureCirc, N, 1)];
if norm_area
    % Normalise to same area
    r_new = sqrt(A_orig / A_new) * r_new;
end

% Plot again
figure;
polar(phi, r_new(:, 2));
hold on;
polar(phi, r_new(:, 1));
```

In this code, a pair of circles disturbed by some filtered random noise is generated - similar to your original drawing (ish). Working in polar co-ordinates, a circle is generated in which the whole original shape fits. The inner points of a second circle are calculated to preserve the distances in the original. If desired, the whole thing is then scaled by the ratio of the areas of the new and original shape.

Example plots:

Original Shape

[image: Original shape]

Generated Shape

[image: Generated shape]

Comment: **I don't think it's possible to preserve both the area and the distance.** Why is that?  Also, what if I wanted to preserve the perimeters of the two circles?  Would the part that scales the two circles according to their areas still work for preserving area?  Also, how are you preserving the distance between the two lines?  Would you say that it is 1-1 mapping?

Comment: As I said in my edit, I now **do** think it's possible to preserve both. But you will have to produce an objective function and optimise it (there may be an analytical expression if you really look into it, but it's probably easier just to optimise numerically). The distance is preserved by calculating the original distance in polar coordinates (based on a reference point at the centre of the original outer circle), generating a new outer circle, and subtracting the original distances from its polar radius to obtain the new inner circle. I have no more characters left to answer your questions.

Comment: **Normalise to same area:** Why do you take the sqrt of the area ratios?  Also, would this method to normalize the area work if the region areas were instead calculated by using the function regionprops?

Comment: It is the radii of the points on the inner circle that must be scaled according to the ratio of the areas. If we had two circles with radii `r1` and `r2`, then `A1 = pi * r1 ^ 2` and `A2 = pi * r2 ^ 2` and `A2 / A1 = (r2 / r1) ^ 2`. Therefore we must take the square root of the area ratio before scaling the radii by it. With regards to using `regionprops`: there is probably a way, but I'm not an image processing person so I don't know it :-) If my answer helped you, please consider accepting.